# How to change image using hover in jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am having a hard time figuring how to switch images inside react. I need the image to switch when I hover over a certain area. The area detection was created by someone else but I am been able to place my first image as the default. But I need to figure out how to change the image when I hover over the area.

This is what the images are imported as

```
import suitcase_open from '../images/suitcase_openEMPTY.png';
import box_open from '../images/discardbox_open.png';
import suitcase_closed from '../images/suitcase_closed.png';
import box_closed from '../images/discardbox_closed.png';
```

These are the two divs where I need to change the image

```
      <div className='bound bound0'>
        <img
          id = 'box'
          src = {box_closed}
        />
      </div>
      <span id='discard'>discard</span>


      <div className='bound bound1' >
        <img id = 'suitcase' src = {suitcase_closed} />
      </div>
      <span id='keep'>keep</span>
```

I was thinking about using onMouseOver but I do not know how to implement the change for the image source. I need to change from the closed to open versions.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need some state to track whether the suitcase is open or closed. You can then use a ternary operator to display the right image. The following code assumes you might also want to set it back to closed when mousing out.

```
function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <img 
      id='suitcase' 
      src={open ? suitcase_open : suitcase_closed} 
      onMouseOver={() => setOpen(true)}
      onMouseOut={() => setOpen(false)}
    />
  )
}
```